# Magento2 HTML Invoice

Tags: magento2, invoice, html, pdf

I have a requirement to print Tamil Unicode characters in Invoice which is not possible with PDF. In magento 1.9 i was using [custom module](http://blog.gaiterjones.com/customiseable-printable-html-invoices-for-magento-free-magento-extension/). Is there a similar kind available for Magento2?

If not some pointers should be help. I am looking for just redirecting PDF output to html.

Comment: Hi, Magento uses Zend_Pdf out of the box. You might be interested in upvoting this feature request for Mgaento 2: https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-Feature-Requests-and/Invoice-shipment-credit-memo-PDFs-Remove-Zend-Pdf-replace-with/idi-p/45879